Saddle point approximation method for an integral containing two branch points.
I am supposed to evaluate the integral, $I(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t\sqrt{z^2+1}}}{\sqrt{z^2+1}\sqrt{z^2+4}-1}$ for larger $t$ using saddle point approximation.
The integrand has the branch points along the imaginary axis $z=\pm i, \pm 2i$ and the branch cut basically lies between $(i, i\infty)\cup(-i, -i\infty)$.
How can I evaluate an integral with an integrand that has two branch points? Which branch point's contribution should be considered dominant? Is it sufficient to expand the corresponding functions around one of the branch point (e.g., $z=i$ for the upper half-plane)?

The function $\sqrt{z^2+1}$ reaches its maximum at the point $z=0$, so you dont have to care about the branch points. Just decompose the integrand near $z=0$

Do you mean $I(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t\sqrt{z^2+1}}}{\sqrt{z^2+1}\sqrt{z^2+4}-1}dz$ ?
